# Predict function in R returns a different value from fitted.value in model object

Tags: r, spatial, spatial-data

I am using `lagsarlm` in spdep package in `r` to estimate a spatial Durbin (mixed) model by

```
m1 <- lagsarlm(f, data = d, wlist, type = "mixed")
```

where `f` is my designed model of dependent variable and independent variables, `d` is a set of data points loaded from csv file, and `wlist` is the spatial weight list. The regression of SDM works fine for me. And I used predict function:

```
pred <- predict(m1,newdata = d, listw = wlist)
```

with the original data and spatial weight list to estimate the dependent variable. The estimation is different from the `fitted.value` in model object `m1`.

From my understanding, the `fitted.value` in an Sarlm object is estimated with assumption that dependent variables are known. I wonder how does the `predict` function estimate a spatial mixed model with lag on both dependent and independent variables.

I checked the documents of sarlm and it provides the information of predicting with spatial lag model. I could not find a prediction formula for the spatial mixed model.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.